# Why is there no way to delete browser cache in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, caching, browser, version-control

I know there are tricks and ways around in naming your files to control the version of the application. But it just doesn't make sense to me why javascript doesn't have a simple way to delete the user's cache on that specific website.
I don't think it causes any security problems, and no developer would use this to slow down their own website!

Since it's something innocent and a very helpful client-side tool for version control and making sure all users have the product up to date. What could the reason be for not something like this to be implemented?

Comment: JavaScript knows nothing about the browser/client that it's running inside of. The code that you can use to interact with the browser (i.e. `document.cookie`, `window.localStorage`, etc.) are all APIs made available by the client itself.

Comment: Content that changes so often that the cache is harmful tend to just go with the dynamic implementation approach - using methods that always ask the server for fresh data (some of these methods include versioning in their approach).

Comment: I saw location.reload(true) but I suppose that's just for the cached html. right?

Comment: In theory there is a way to do this, it's not trivial like.  It's possible to create a service worker and implement your own fetch, and then your responsible for doing the cache.